# Can't push angular app for production - Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, module, production-environment

I have a problem with push app for production. Locally everything works perfect. But when I use 'ng build --prod --base-href "https:///p"' I reveive communicate like bellow:

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'SimpleSmoothScrollModule in 
/home/magda/Desktop/portfolioTest/portfolio_angular4/node_modules/ng2-
simple-smooth-scroll/lib/index.js' imported by the module 'AppModule 
in/home/magda/Desktop/portfolioTest/portfolio_angular4/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

What can be wrong? Below is my app.module.ts file also.

```
import { AboutMeComponent } from './about-me/about-me.component';
import { InitialNavComponent } from './initial-nav/initial-
nav.component';
import { IntroductionComponent } from 
'./introduction/introduction.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from './skills/skills.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgsRevealModule } from 'ng-scrollreveal'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SimpleSmoothScrollModule } from 'ng2-simple-smooth-scroll';
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InitialNavComponent,
    AboutMeComponent,
    IntroductionComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    SkillsComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgsRevealModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    SimpleSmoothScrollModule,
    BsModalModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Does the SimpleSmoothScrollModule have a forRoot()?

Comment: There are plenty of things that may not allow you to run `ng build -prod`. 
try to run it with  `--sourcemaps`  flag for more details. 
And check on github in issues